Selecting all non-blank cells in variable range in Excel to export
I have a data set in Excel. Starting at column C, it has continuous data from C2 to a number that changes every time it is used.
For every row of continuous data in column D, I want to select column C-J's rows as well. I'm trying to select this data to create a new Excel workbook with that data.
When I run:
Dim lastVal As Range, sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Sheets("sheet1")

Set lastVal = sht.Columns(4).Find("*", sht.Cells(1, 48), xlValues, _
                                xlPart, xlByColumns, xlPrevious)

Debug.Print lastVal.Address

sht.Range("C2", lastVal).Resize(, 48).Select
selection.copy

Set Objexcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
objexcel.visible = True
objexcel.cells(1, 1).paste

I get:

run-time error '13': type mismatch

on the Set LastVal line.

"doesnt seem to be working" please describe the exact problem you're having with your code.  Are you getting an error message?  If Yes, what error is it, and on which line?   There's no need to create a new Excel Application object here - you can use WorkBooks.Add if you want a new file to paste the data into

im getting a run-time error '13': type mismatch

On which line ?

Set LastVal line.

The After parameter of Find needs to be a single cell in the range you searching through. sht.Cells(1, 48) is not in sht.Columns(4).

with that change i get a new error on the same line error 9 subscript out of range.

Something like this:
Sub Tester()
    Dim sht As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, shtNew As Worksheet
    
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1") 'or activeworkbook
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add() 'add new workbook
    Set shtNew = wb.Worksheets(1)

    'copy from Col C, using last row from Col D?
    'not sure if that's really what you want though?
    With sht.Range("C2:J" & sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
        Debug.Print "copying", .Address
        'straight copy
        .Copy shtNew.Range("A1")
        '...or copy values only
        shtNew.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub

In place of sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "D") you can use any other column in which you don't have any blanks.
